# How to split rows in stacks and perform `select` for every single in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have 100 rows in my CSV file, I need to split them into 10 rows and perform some queries for every single stacks, because some rows have a specific column and some of them not.
How can I do it in **Pandas**?

```
1      blue     1      NaN
2    yellow     0      NaN
3    yellow     1      NaN
4      blue     1      NaN
5      blue     1      NaN
6      blue     0      NaN
7    yellow     1      NaN
8    yellow     1      NaN
9    yellow     1      NaN
10     blue     0      NaN

11    yellow     NaN      1
12      blue     NaN      1
13    yellow     NaN      1
14    yellow     NaN      0
15      blue     NaN      1
16    yellow     NaN      1
17    yellow     NaN      0
18      blue     NaN      1
19      blue     NaN      0
20      blue     NaN      1
```

I used PsychoPy for a neuroscience task and the task has 10 trials, because of that PsychoPy stores RTs (Reaction Times) in different 10 columns, so I need to access them to for example evaluating blue circles in the first trial which their RTs is 1 or yellow circles in second trial which their RTs is 0.

Comment: please post a sample operation and the equivalent expected output for better understanding

Comment: you want to split your dataframe into segments of 10 rows?how do you want to hold it in a csv, list or dictionary of dataframes?

Comment: `df.groupby(df.index // 10)...`

Comment: As @anky_91 said please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: @anky_91 I added more information.

Comment: @Erfan Thanks, exactly what I wanted, can you please answer my question and tell me how to use `np.select` for every single of the stacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just reorganize your data for easier access.  Given that all bar one of the reaction time columns is null, just sum them up to get the non-null value in a single column `reaction_time`.  Then assign a new `trial` column via `1 + df.index // trials`.

Now you can use `.loc` to access the `reaction_time` data by `trial` and `color`.

```
# Sample data.
nan = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'color': ['blue', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'blue', 'yellow',  'blue', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'blue', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue'],
     'num_1': [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0] + [nan] * 10,
     'num_2': [nan] * 10 + [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]}
)

# Summary data result.
trials = 10
reaction_time = df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(axis=1)
df2 = df[['color']].assign(
    reaction_time=reaction_time,
    trial=1 + df.index // trials,
)
>>> df2
     color  reaction_time  trial
0     blue            1.0      1
1   yellow            0.0      1
2   yellow            1.0      1
3     blue            1.0      1
4     blue            1.0      1
5     blue            0.0      1
6   yellow            1.0      1
7   yellow            1.0      1
8   yellow            1.0      1
9     blue            0.0      1
10  yellow            1.0      2
11    blue            1.0      2
12  yellow            1.0      2
13  yellow            0.0      2
14    blue            1.0      2
15  yellow            1.0      2
16  yellow            0.0      2
17    blue            1.0      2
18    blue            0.0      2
19    blue            1.0      2

# Query data.
>>> df2.loc[df2.trial.eq(2) & df2.color.eq('yellow')]
     color  reaction_time  trial
10  yellow            1.0      2
12  yellow            1.0      2
13  yellow            0.0      2
15  yellow            1.0      2
16  yellow            0.0      2
```

Answer (score 0):

`batches = [df.loc[i:i+10] for i in range(0, df.shape[0], 10)]`

```
for batch in batches:
    select_function()
```